# Issue with output stringstream in multi-threaded environment

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am implementing a logger that needs to work in multi threaded environment.

This i have implemented as a singleton class

```
class myLog {
    // Implementation
};
```

To provide a clean and easy interface, i provided some macro's

```
#define MY_LOG_DEBUG MY_LOG(LOG_MSG, DEBUG)
static ostringstream log_msg;

#define MY_LOG(LOG_MSG, DEBUG) {\
get_lock();\
log_msg << LOG_MSG; \
myLog::getInstance().dump(log_msg, DEBUG);\
log_msg.str("");\
get_unlock();\
}
```

Issue is this works fine but on more often in multithread environment, i get instances where log dumped is not complete, or jumbled up, or missed some characters.

I am suspecting this can be because of :

1. Output stream not getting flushed tried setbuf(stdout, NULL)
2. Output string stream container not getting cleared after each write to output stream

What are the ways to clear the above two doubts in multi-thread scenario ?

P.S. : Using a pretty old enough gcc 4.4.5 :(

Comment: What does `get_lock()` do?

Comment: @Galik : mutex lock and unlock

Comment: Can you provide the code?

Comment: I was wondering how you were locking but I just noticed that you do this: `log_msg.str();` which does not clear the `stringstream`. Maybe you meant to do this: `log_msg.str("");`?

Comment: @galik : yes that is correct. i made a typo

Comment: Are you sure that `get_lock()` and `get_unlock()` are dealing with the same instance of the mutex across all your threads? 

Also your `#define MY_LOG {` looks strange because you didn't declare its parameters i.e. `#define MY_LOG(LOG_MSG, DEBUG) {`

Comment: @mikhail : yes, both lock and unlock use the same mutex.

Answer (score 0):

Issue got resolved when i use a per thread buffer.

```
static __thread char buffer[BUFF_LEN];
```

However, i am still not sure about the behaviour of string stream in case of multi thread environment.